# Can't see complete stackpanel in printout

Tags: c#, wpf, events, printing

I've been trying to print out my data column headers by using stackpanels which is working and I get my printout.  The only problem is that my stackpanel gets cut off after a fixed width and I'm not sure which property is responsible for it.  It's like the printer only sees a rectangular limit over my stackpanel that has width shorter than my stackpanel and only prints what is in the rectangle. Can't really explain it too well without a picture but I don't have a scanner.

Heres my code for it:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            List<Result> results = vm.ObsResults.OrderByDescending(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.SchedulingRate)).ToList();
            var propList = typeof(Result).GetProperties().ToList();
            int maxRowsPerPage = 42;

            var pgCnt = results.Count / maxRowsPerPage;

            XpsDocumentWriter docWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(dialog.PrintQueue);
            PrintTicket ticket = new PrintTicket();
            ticket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

            for (int pgNum = 0; pgNum <= pgCnt; pgNum++)
            {
                //Title
                Canvas c = new Canvas();
                c.Width = 1024;
                c.Height = 768;
                TextBlock tbTitle = new TextBlock();
                tbTitle.Text = " Results " + vm.ObsDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                tbTitle.FontSize = 16;
                Canvas.SetLeft(tbTitle, 20);
                Canvas.SetTop(tbTitle, 10);
                c.Children.Add(tbTitle);

                //Column Headers
                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal , Width = 885};
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "Unit Name", Width = 150, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "Unit ID", Width = 65, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "Schedule", Width = 65, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "TPS", Width = 25, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "TTS", Width = 35, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "Min Run", Width = 50, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "Schd RT", Width = 50, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) }});
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "MW", Width = 35, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "00", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "01", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "02", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "03", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "04", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "05", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "06", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "07", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "08", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "09", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "10", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "11", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "12", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "13", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "14", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "15", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "16", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "17", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "18", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "19", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "20", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "21", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "22", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "23", Width = 15, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                sp.Children.Add(new Border() { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1), Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "Constraint", Width = 100, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) } });
                Canvas.SetLeft(sp, 20);
                Canvas.SetTop(sp, 35);
                c.Children.Add(sp);

                int idxStart = pgNum * maxRowsPerPage;
                int idxEnd = Math.Min(results.Count, idxStart + maxRowsPerPage);

                int topMargin = 3;

               }
                c.Measure(new Size(Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MaxValue));
                c.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), c.DesiredSize));

                FixedPage fxdPg = new FixedPage();
                fxdPg.Children.Add(c);
                PageContent pgContent = new PageContent();
                ((IAddChild)pgContent).AddChild(fxdPg);
                fxdDoc.Pages.Add(pgContent);
            }

            docWriter.WriteAsync(fxdDoc, ticket);
        }
    }
```

It looks like this where it gets cut off:

```
00 | 01 | 02 | ... |18 | 19 | 2/  <cut off.
```

No 21, 22, 23, headers.

Comment: Learn about styles, this copy-paste makes things unreadable.  Chances are your page is larger than the `Canvas`, which you could easily test for if you had a `Style` defined for your textboxes and borders. StackPanel isn't limited in Width or Height - it calculates it from the child elements

Comment: this part of the code is only in the codebehind, I don't have anything regarding the printing in the XAML.  Is there a property of the canvas that I can change to fix this? I see the c.Width and c.Height settings but even when I set them to 1920 and 1080, respectively, there's no change in the printout.

Comment: can you put a screenshot of your printout on pastebin or something?

Comment: sorry, I don't have a scanner, and there being no XAML, no way to preview it digitally.

It looks like this where it gets cut off:

 00 | 01 | 02 | ... |18 | 19 | 2/  <cut off. 


    No 21, 22, 23, headers.

Comment: yes... sounds very impossible to preview... make it a xaml, chances are you'll see the issue there. There are too many issues with this code for me to divine where's the problem.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to manually build a Table, why don't you use a DataGrid instead of a StackPanel? Doesn't look like you are putting data into it anyways.